# How to get normal taskbar when minimizing games?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, window, gaming

When I minimize almost any game (e.g. Alt+Esc in X4 with borderless window), then go to desktop (Win+D), then unminimize any maximized window (e.g. Firefox), the taskbar disappears and instead I see the game as a background. How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Why not just Alt-Tab normally?

Comment: replacing Alt+Esc with Alt+Tab changes nothing in my scenario

Comment: My games minimize properly as soon as I switch away. I do not use Win+D at all, because I don’t have to. That also means the game does not pop back up when I "undo" Win+D by activating any window.

Comment: @DanielB then how would you go to desktop? when I alt+tab from game and then minimize that window the game appears below it